# Problema al cambiar un bindingsource de un datagridview

Tags: vb.net

El problema que me surge es el siguiente:

Cuando cambio el `BindingSource`de un `DataGridView` en `vb.net` en un `BackgroundWorker`, obtengo el siguiente error:

> system indexoutofrangeexception el índice 0 no tiene un valor, en System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.gey_Item(Int32idex) en System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConeccion.GetError(Int32 rowIndex"

El error no salta siempre, hay veces que funciona correctamente, pero cuando hago el cambio seguido, salta el error ¿alguien sabe porque? ¿cómo solucionar el error? 
El bindingsource se actualizar mediante un datatable por un query
algo asi:

```
    Dim b as new bindingsource
dim data as new datatable
dim datagrid as new datagridview
datagrid.datasource = b
b.datasource = data
AddHandler aplicarndocambios.DoWork, AddressOf procesoderellenado
Public aplicarndocambios As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Sub procesoderellenado()
dim adap as new mysqldataadapter ("consulta")
adap.Fill(data)
end sub
```

En la parte de adap, saltee un poco de codigo, pero basicamente hace la consulta, y actualiza "Data" y funciona correctamente, el error no sale siempre

Comment: Seguramente se debe a una condición carrera en el hilo. ¿Estas leyendo un indice de una colección y a la vez en otro hilo agregando a la misma colección?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que te pases por [ask] y tambien que hagas el [tour]

Comment: no, lo que hago es actualizar un sql, es decir un datatable que esta anexado al bindingsource

Comment: De que tipo es la collection con la que haces el binding?

Comment: acabo de añadir un poco de código, para que se entienda mejor, disculpen la falta de detalle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de días de frustración encontré el problema, cuando un datagridview se edita desde un backgroundworker, salta el error(supuestamente porque si llamo muy seguido a la actualizacion, vb.net no tiene tiempo para dibujar la tabla , al actualizar una vez el proceso tiene un tiempo de proceso y al interrumpirlo con una segunda actualización se interrumpe el dibujó del proceso de actualización anterior, lo que lei es que si necesario invocar la actualizacion de forma independiente con el comando invoque y como eso era muy complejo lo solucione con un timer

```
 ' primero defino una variable de tiempo para llevar un conteo para realizar una consulta
 Dim tiempoderecargado as  integer
 Dim rellenarpendiente as boolean 
'Cuando se requiera realizar el quiery de la base de datos y actualizar los datos en los campos se llama a la siguiente sub
 Sub rellenado
 If tiempoderecargado = 0 then 
Tiempoderecargado = 1
 Else 
Rellenarpendiente=true
 End if 
End sub
 'Seguido el timer para controlar un reposo en cada consulta, de esta forma no saturó el servidor de base de datos y no se cuelga el programa 
Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
            If tiempoderecargado > 0 Then
                If tiempoderecargado = 1 or( rellenarpendiente and tiempoderecargado= 100)Then
                 Using adaptador as new mysqladapter("consulta sal")
                Adaptador.fill(data)
                End using

                End If
                tiempoderecargado += 1
                If tiempoderecargado > 100 Then
                    rellenarpendiente= true

                    tiempoderecargado = 0
                End If
            End If
```

Espero que les sirva